# LOCATION type in QB CUSTOM OBJECT

Tags: quickblox

With the last release of Quickblox SDK there is a new LOCATION field type, meaning we can save gps coordinates.

My question is: are or will be there specific functions/methods to query on this kind of field?

For instance, can I get all records in a CUSTOM OBJECT class that are located with 10 kms of my current location? - (based on a location field in the class)

Can I order the result by distance from my location?

These kind of queries are available in the LOCATION module.

Until now we were queering LOCATION to get something like "all users within 10 kms of my location" and then using those users ID's to query CUSTOM OBJECT and get specific information about those users.

With the new LOCATION field can we do this using only CUSTOM OBJECTS?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary new];    
params[@"field_name[near]"] = @"34.0013123, 15.014915; 40000";
```

To avoid name conflicts, try to give a plural name to location field.